# Custom font causes delay in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I tried to change a label font to bodoni 72 but every time I test the app, it freezes for about 2 seconds before it starts. The default font is verdana and that works fine but as soon as I switch it, the app goes nuts. I even put the font file in the supporting files folder.

```
      scoreLabel.fontName = "Bodoni 72"
```

That's the code but doesn't work. But the code below does...

```
      scoreLabel.fontName = "Verdana"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the incorrect font name in SpriteKit it causes a delay while it tries to find a match.

In this case "Bodoni 72" is the font family name, but it isn't the font name.  If you open the Font Book application on your Mac and have a look at Bodoni 72 you will see that you can expand it to see the three actual fonts in this family - 'Book', 'Book italic' and 'Bold'.

If you change your code to read

```
scoreLabel.fontName = "Bodoni 72 Book"
```

then the delay will be gone.

Comment: Now I was trying out a different font. It's called "Braggadocio", and that one doesn't work and there is no "Braggadocio Book" or anything like that.

Comment: From FontBook it should be "Braggadocio" or "Braggadocio Regular"  but I can't get this font to work in a sprite or in a UIButton, even if I add it to the Xcode project - I suspect that there is some sort of compatibility problem with the file - It is a Microsoft office font so maybe that is something to do with it

Comment: i keep trying other fonts from frontbook but none work. Do I need to add the file to the project?

Answer (score -1):

That's not an issue with Xcode or Swift. That's an issue in your code. Instead of that, try setting the `fontName` of your label to `"Bodoni"`, and your `fontSize` (the size of your font **as a float**) to `72.0`.

See below:

```
scoreLabel.fontName = "Bodoni"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 72
```

If you want to set the color of a label (this might only be in `SpriteKit`'s `SKLabelNode`s), you can use this:

```
scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor //replace with your color
```

Comment: In this case the font family name is "Bodoni 72", the 72 isn't the size.